# How to develop a remote control using note 3 IR blaster

Tags: android, open-source, samsung-mobile

I have been searching the web for a working example on using **IR blaster** of note 3 in eclipse. There are many answers but ***non*** get you to the end. I want to be able to use any IR code and transmit it using the IR blaster. Any **API**? **Library**? **Open Source app** to learn from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Someone figured out how to access the IR blaster of a Galaxy Tab 2 over at xda-developers and even put together a project on github: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1670289.  The code should also work on the Note series.

Basically, it's a system service than you can access and communicate to via Reflection..

Comment: Thank you, this is the first direct answer I get after searching for 2 week